# ng repeat nested loop

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-loops

I am facing an issue while displaying the nested data inside the ng-repeat. I get data for the first 4 fields but those which are more nested like the label and onwards field data do not show up. the last 5 fields appear to be empty and does not fetch the data. Will be glad if anyone could help troubleshoot the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <!-- <p>Today's welcome message is:</p> -->


    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th>deliveryRecipient</th>
        <th>Pick Up Locality</th>
        <th>Delivery Locality</th>
        <th>Created On</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>category</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Action</th>

      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in myWelcome">
        <td>{{x.deliveryRecipient}}</td>
        <td>{{x.pickupLocality}}</td>
        <td>{{x.deliveryLocality}}</td>
        <td>{{x.createdOn}}</td>
        <td>{{x.label}}</td>
        <td>{{x.category}}</td>
        <td>{{x.actualPriceLabel}}</td>
        <td>{{x.weight}}</td>
        <td>{{x.quantity}}</td>
        <td><button onclick="showgraphqldata()" type="button" class="view">View</button></td>

      </tr>
      <td ng-repeat="y in x.items">
      <td>
        <tr ng-repeat="z in y">
          <td>{{z.label}}</td>
          <td>{{z.category}}</td>
          <td>{{z.actualPriceLabel}}</td>
          <td>{{z.weight}}</td>
          <td>{{z.quantity}}</td>

        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{x.uid}}" />
      
    </table>
  </div>


  <!-- <p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome"
    variable.</p> -->

  <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api-stg.martcart.pk/api/v1/merchants/incomingOrders?archived=false&isIncomingOrders=true&isPurchaseOrders=true&loadItems=true&pageNumber=1&recordsPerPage=100&statusIn=NEW,VIEWED",
        headers: {
          datatype: 'JSON',
          
          , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;

      }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.view', function () {

      var uid = $(this).parent().prev().val();
     
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

attached images are the responses if json data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pptu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eANro.png)

Comment: Please post the response JSON rather than exposing api credentials.

Comment: the json response is too long to post here

Comment: Can you give a minimal sample of the response? I'd highly recommend removing the Bearer token from the description

Comment: removed the authorization token and added the images of json responses

Comment: The </tr> in <tr ng-repeat="x in myWelcome"></tr> is ending the scope of your 'x' in your ng-repeat so that any html after </tr> has no clue what 'x'. You need to figure out a way to include the following <tr ng-repeat='y in x.items'> within that first <tr> block. One suggestion is take your JSON, remodel it so that there is only 1 ng-repeat. Use ng-ifs when you havent shown those item rows yet.